# What is this inequality called: $x + y \geq 2\sqrt{xy}$?

Tags: calculus, inequality

Apparently it's a famous inequality taught in 1st year calculus but I have never even seen it before nor know it has a name.

$x + y \geq 2\sqrt{xy}$

It looks like it is just saying $(x + y)^2 \geq 4xy$, so it's somehow derived from sum of squares?

What is the name (if it even has one) of this inequality?

Comment: i never heard about this fame...

Comment: Check out the wiki page- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called the AM-GM or Arithmetic Mean-Geometric Mean inequality. It generalizes to
$$\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}{n}\geq \sqrt[n]{x_1\cdots x_n}$$
and more information on it can be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM-GM_inequality).

Comment: AHHHH That's the name!

Answer (score 5):

In addition to being an example of the AM-GM inequality as explained in other answers, it can also be interpreted as a special case of [Young's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality):
$$ab \le \frac{a^p}{p}+\frac{b^q}{q} \text{, where } \frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} = 1$$

Set $a=\sqrt x$, $b=\sqrt y$, and $p=q=2$.

Answer (score 3):

For positive numbers, the arithmetic mean is at least as big as the geometric mean.  The arithmetic mean is
$$
\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}{n}
$$
and the geometric mean is
$$
(x_1\cdots x_n)^{1/n}.
$$
The inequality you've written is the special case in which $n=2$.

See this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic-geometric_mean_inequality

**Later note:** The two means are equal only if $x_1=\cdots=x_n$.

Answer (score 3):

Well, *after* one gets into this inequality soul it can even be called "trivial", as you can check that

$$x+y\geq 2\sqrt{xy}\Longleftrightarrow (x+y)^2\geq 4xy\Longleftrightarrow (x-y)^2\geq 0$$

Of course, the basic assumption is $\,x\,,\,y\geq 0\,$ .